# Add a column whose value is based on max of another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have the following data

```
game    name    score
A       Jon     100
A       Jon     110
A       Jen     105
B       Jen     110
B       Jon     100
B       Jon     105
```

I would like to add a column to the data that contains the name of the player with the highest score for each game without losing any of the rows in the data or performing a join.

```
game    name    score   best_player
A       Jon     100     Jon
A       Jon     110     Jon
A       Jen     105     Jon
B       Jen     115     Jen
B       Jon     100     Jen
B       Jon     105     Jen
```

Is there a SQL query that will add the best player column without requiring any joins? I could get the highest score using the following query

```
select *, max(score) over(partition by game) as highscore


game    name    score   highscore
A       Jon     100     110
A       Jon     110     110
A       Jen     105     110
B       Jen     115     115
B       Jon     100     115
B       Jon     105     115
```

However I'm not sure how to pull the name for the highest scoring player into a new column just using an analytic function that does not collapse the data or use a join.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `first_value()`:

```
select *, max(score) over (partition by game) as highscore,
       first_value(name) over (partition by game order by score desc) as highscorer
```

Answer (score 2):

This is precisely what window functions like `first_value` are for.

```
select 
    *,
    first_value(name) OVER w as highscore_name,
    first_value(score) OVER w AS highscore
FROM mytable
WINDOW w AS (partition by game ORDER BY score DESC)
```